# drupal 8 node->setTitle

Tags: php, encryption, drupal-8, encryption-symmetric

I'm trying to store encrypted data in my d8 database, and decrypt it to display it to authorised users:

```
use \Defuse\Crypto\Key;
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;

function my_module_node_load($nodes) {    
    $key = loadEncryptionKeyFromConfig();
    $title = $nodes[1]->getTitle(); // $title is "def369u8765"
    $decrypted_title = Crypto::decrypt($title, $key); //$decrypted_title is 'a test note'
    $nodes[1]->setTitle($decrypted_title);
    $nodes[1]->getTitle(); // returns 'a test note'
    return $nodes;
}
```

When it actually gets displayed on my page, it's still the encrypted version. In the db, node_field_revision still shows the encrypted version, and the timestamp is unchanged since yesterday.

What am I doing wrong? how should I be returning the decrypted version?

I do NOT want to decrypt it in my database. It must remain encrypted on disk.

EDIT: I added $nodes[1]->save(); and it (predictably) went into an infinite loop because node_load is called as part of the save() process.

EDIT: I do know that I shouldn't hard code the [1]! Once I've got this one node sorted, I'll put this into a loop over all the nid's in $nodes

Answer (score 1):

Turns out caching was tripping me up - the code works fine.

```
drupal cr all
```

did the trick.

I'm new to drupal x, don't judge me

Answer (score 0):

I have similar kind of requirement, resolved using

```
use Drupal\views\Views;
function my_module_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {   

// parse node $build

}
```

OR in preprocess theme hook

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$variables) { 
}
```